# Опечатка при вызове тревоги

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, тревоги

Не уверен, что правильно сделал, задав здесь такой вопрос, но тем не менее.

Будьте добры, исправьте, пожалуйста, очепятку в слове "качаства" (качества), глаза режет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кстати, а в каком случае у Васиотображалось это сообщение? Просто я вижу, например, 'на текущий момент вы отметили этой тревогой' или после отмены 'вы уже изменяли тревогу "низкого качества"'.

Comment: @alexolut, точно не помню, как это произошло тогда, но сейчас у меня оно отображается при нажатии на вопрос, который раньше отмечал тревогой, имеющей сейчас статус "спорная".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Немного переформулировал так:

> Вы уже использовали тревогу о низком качестве сообщения

Будет доступно на сайте при следующей сборке после подгрузки с transifex.